# How can I use a FOR loop to create circles in a circle (in Processing)

Tags: for-loop, geometry, 2d, processing, trigonometry

I need to create a loop which will space circles equally around a circle in Processing.

I know I can somehow implement a FOR loop.

I need to be able to increase or decrease the number of circles around this circle (with button presses) but keep them equally spaced.

I know the formula's I need to include in the FOR loop to get the X and Y axis. The formulas:

```
being
   X = R*cos(angle-90)+Y0
   Y = R*sin(angle-90)+X0
```

I understand the three parameters of the FOR loop; when does it start, when does it finish, what changes when it runs.

What I can't see is how to implement the formulas into the FOR loop.

Many thanks

Here is the code I do have

```
void setup () {
  size (600, 600);
  background (255, 255, 255);
  smooth ();
  ellipse (width/2, height/2, 200, 200); // the guide circle. Not needed in final code.
}


void draw() {


  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j ++) {

      ellipse (i *20, j * 20, 20, 20);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to just put X number of circles inside some other circle? If so, post what you've tried in the form of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Or are you trying to fit as many circles in as possible? If so, check out [circle packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_theorem).

Comment: @KevinWorkman

I need to write a sketch where n circles (between 2 and 10) are equally spaced around a circle. I need n to be adjustable by the user of the sketch using left and right mouse buttons or '+' and '-' or similar.

I want to use a FOR loop for equally spacing n circles using the formulas in my question. 

Whilst I can use FOR loops for basic things like grids and rows of shapes, I can't see how to put them in a circle and equally spaced.

The bit most confusing is how the formulas are added to the FOR loop parameters.

Thanks for taking the time to read / reply.

Comment: It's not homework, it's an end of chapter exercise. 

I'm trying to put circles around a circle. I don't think circle packing is what I'm after.

The minimum number of circles is 2. The max number is 10. They need to remain equally spaced as more circles are added through key presses.

What I'm most stuck on is how to get the formulas for x and y co-ords into the FOR loop.

Comment: @Jdoh Okay, I see. I agree circle packing isn't what you're after. Here's a hint: You've got a formula (involving sin and cos). You know the R value (it's the radius of the circle). X0 and Y0 are just the center of the circle. Now all you need is the angle. That's what the for loop is for. If you want to add 10 circles, you create a for loop that starts the angle at 0, then increments it by 36 each iteration. When the angle reaches 360, you've gone the whole way around the circle.

Comment: Thank you Kevin.

Will I need multiple loops. One for n=10, n=9, n=8...n=2?

As you said, A is incremented by 36 for n=10, do I write a similar loop for n=9 but it is incremented by 40? (360/9).

Thanks again. Your last comment made everything much clearer. Not clear yet, but I'm getting there :)

Comment: @Jdoh (btw, I don't get a notification if you don't tag me in your comment) No, you won't need separate loops for each N value. You can parameterize that in a variable. Just try it out with a hardcoded N (like 10) and see what patterns you notice, then try to generalize to any N value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
    float incrementalAngle = 0.0;

void setup(){
  size(600, 600);
  smooth();
  background(0);

  ellipse(width/2, height/2, 200, 200);
  drawCircles(20, 200);
}

void draw(){

}

void drawCircles(int circlesNumber, int bigCircleNumber){
  float angle = incrementalAngle;

  for(int i = 0; i < circlesNumber; i++){
    ellipse(bigCircleNumber * cos(incrementalAngle) + height/2, 
            bigCircleNumber * sin(incrementalAngle) + width/2, 
            circlesNumber, circlesNumber);
    incrementalAngle += TWO_PI / circlesNumber;  
  } 
}
```

[image: Here is the output]

So the second loop wasn't needed, and the formula you were trying to introduce would go in the X and Y position of your ellipse, there by playing whit the angle and the cos and sin you can get the result you were looking for.

What's left now is for you to get the number of circles you want by the clicking inside a `mousePressed()` method and drawing that amount.

Hope this comes useful and call me if you need more help

Regards
Jose.

Comment: It's great that you're trying to help, but you really should consider walking the OP through the process instead of just dumping syntax here. Spoon-feeding isn't helpful.

Comment: Don't be so hard... I'll take the advice for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who helped.

I managed to do it (slightly differently to you @Jose Gonzalez

```
   int nbr_circles = 2;
void setup() {    
  size(600, 600);

  smooth();
  background(255);
} 

void draw() { 
  background(255);
  float cx = width/2.0;
  float cy = height/2.0;
  fill(0);
  //float x, y; //  
  for (int i = 0; i < nbr_circles; i++) 
  {
    float angle = i * TWO_PI / nbr_circles;
    float x = cx + 110.0 * cos(angle);                
    float y = cy + 110.0 * sin(angle);                
    ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
  }
}

void mousePressed() {

  if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
    if (nbr_circles < 20)
    nbr_circles = nbr_circles + 1;

  } else if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    if (nbr_circles > 2) 
      nbr_circles = nbr_circles - 1;

  }
}
```